# How to do "SUDO UPDATE and SUDO UPGRADE" without errors (NEWBIE)

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, sudo, update-manager

Just check out the file attached to this link
http://1drv.ms/1yQpeTH to understand the situation

Comment: You are using an unsupported release. If it is a fresh install , I would suggest you to re-install a supported version or see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) to upgrade it into a supported release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using an outdated End Of Life (EOL) version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 12.10
Quantal Quetzal.

Upgrade to a newer version. Latest Long Term Support release is 14.04.

Also, please consider using pastebin next time rather than One Drive. Not sure about on a PC, but annoying on mobile.

Edit:

If this was a fresh install, rather than update process your better off downloading and installing latest from fresh iso.

Comment: yeah it is true..now i am using ubuntu 14.10 and it works awesome

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(assuming here that you have your sources configured properly)

Answer (score -1):

Either your apt-get can't access Internet or your package mirror is down. In second case, edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and replace your country code `in.archieve..` to `us.archieve`. Don't forget to change back later.